# Subverting Rust's type system for printf-style debugging

Tags: serialization, types, rust

I am working on a `serde` `Serializer` implementation and I would like to debug values while deep inside the machinery. Namely, I want to debug the values passed in to a sequence serializer -- I would like to bomb out of my `cargo test` run with the value that is currently being serialized.

```
fn serialize_seq_elt<T>(&mut self, value: T) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where T: Serialize {
    Err(CdrError{
        reason: format!("{:?}", value)
    })
//        value.serialize(self) // previous, type checked-code
}
```

and as anticipated, I have an error at compile time:

```
   Compiling rtps v0.1.0 (file:///Users/xavierlange/code/dds/rtps)
src/cdr/ser.rs:98:37: 98:42 error: the trait bound `T: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/cdr/ser.rs:98             reason: format!("{:?}", value)
                                                      ^~~~~
```

it's true that `serde Serializer` doesn't enforce the `Debug` trait. Is there a macro or some other way to get around it? Do I need to hack `serde` library to add that associated trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I thought of one solution: leverage the serde_json library which is guaranteed to accept the `Serialize` types flowing through the `serialize_seq` call:

```
fn serialize_seq_elt<T>(&mut self, value: T) -> Result<(), Self::Error> where T: Serialize {
    let reason_str = serde_json::to_string(&value).unwrap();
    Err(CdrError{
        reason: reason_str
    })
//        value.serialize(self)
}
```

this work out very nicely and formats pretty much the way I would do it anyway!

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with a newtype and specialization like this:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::fmt;

struct TryDebug<T>(T);

impl<T> fmt::Debug for TryDebug<T> {
    default fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        write!(f, "no std::fmt::Debug impl")
    }
}

impl<T: fmt::Debug> fmt::Debug for TryDebug<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        self.0.fmt(f)
    }
}

struct Foo;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", TryDebug(1));
    println!("{:?}", TryDebug("foo"));
    println!("{:?}", TryDebug(Foo));
}
```

Output:

```
1
"foo"
no std::fmt::Debug impl
```

Note: Specialization is an unstable feature as of today. You'll have to use Rust Nightly for this to work.

Comment: Oh, this is a really interesting general solution

Comment: Could you discuss some of the downsides of using specialization in this manner?

Comment: @Shepmaster is there any downside I should be aware of (except that it requires nightly and may break before it's stabilized)? This is the first time I've used specialization in a program after reading the original RFC.

Comment: I was mostly thinking of things like [(the lack of) parametricity](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3yuk9w/a_pr_for_specialization_just_appeared/cygzuf5), but was also hoping that you'd have more ideas ^_^.

Comment: One of the obvious downsides is that you need a newtype wrapper. I think it is not always possible or convenient to use it.

Comment: I like this code but it was more complex than the specific problem I was trying to solve. You definitely address the spirit of the title very well but I ended up just needing the serde-specific solution. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: there is a package that does this now: [debugit](https://crates.io/crates/debugit).  It has a sensible fallback for Rust stable too.